# making 3d array with arma::cube in Rcpp shows cube error

Tags: arrays, r, rcpp, bayesian

I am making a Rcpp code for Gibbs sampling. Inside the code, I first want to make a 3 dimensional array with row number= number of iteration (500), column number=number of parameter(4) and slice number= number of chain(3). I wrote it in this way:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <math.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]


using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

//Gibbs sampling code starts here

Rcpp::List mcmc(const int iter,const int chains, const NumericVector data){
  arma::cube posteriorC = arma::zeros(iter, 5, chains);
  \\ rest of the codes
   List out(Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("posteriorC") =posteriorC));
   return out;
}
```

. While compelling it does not show any error. But when I want to run the code with:

```
res<- mcmc(iter=500,chains=2,data)
```

it shows the error:

```
Error: Cube::operator(): index out of bounds
```

. I want to know if there any mistake while making the 3D array. **Please note that I want to get estimates of 5 parameters of my model.**

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the template for `arma::zeros` to correctly fill an `arma::cube`, c.f. [`arma::zeros<template>`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#zeros_standalone)

> Generate a vector, matrix or cube with the elements set to zero
>
> Usage:
>
> - `vector_type v = zeros<vector_type>( n_elem )`
> - `matrix_type X = zeros<matrix_type>( n_rows, n_cols )`
> - `matrix_type Y = zeros<matrix_type>( size(X) )`
> - `cube_type Q = zeros<cube_type>( n_rows, n_cols, n_slices )`
> - `cube_type R = zeros<cube_type>( size(Q) )`

Thus, in your case it would be:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List mcmc(const int iter, const int chains,
                const Rcpp::NumericVector data){


    arma::cube posteriorC = arma::zeros<arma::cube>(iter, 5, chains);
    // --------------------------------- ^^^^^^^^

    // Not Shown

    Rcpp::List out = Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("posteriorC") =posteriorC);
    return out;
}
```

Two final notes:

1. You explicitly state that the code as it stands now will create *4* columns to store *4* variables. However, you explicitly mention that you needed to estimate *5* parameters. You may need to increase this to prevent an out of bounds when saving into the `arma::cube` slices.
2. The way the `Rcpp::List out` is being created isn't quite correct. In general, the best way to create the list is to do: `Rcpp::List out = Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("Blah"), Blah);`

Comment: @ coatless, Thank you so much. But it did not work for me. :(. Does not show any error while writing or compiling. Can I use both arma::cube and Rcpp::NumericVector at once? Or I have always need to use only arma???

Comment: @gultu I have 0 clue as to what is happening in your MCMC routine as you've omitted it. I cannot diagnose _why_ it isn't working for you as the information I have is sparse and related directly to the instantiation of the `arma::cube`.

Comment: @ coatless, the main code is very long and is complicated. Shall I post it here?

Comment: @gultu in that case just switch the `Rcpp::NumericVector` to `arma::cube`. This assumes you are passing a 3D _R_ Array to _C++_.

Comment: @ coatless,  I did not understand this. Can I show you my full code? I do not know how to do that.

Comment: Try with the correct way of forming the `Rcpp::List` given above.